# Apache2 Virtual Hosts Guide for Subdomains

Tags: debian, domain, subdomain, apache2, a-record

I am trying to set up a subdomain that serves a different website that what my main domain name serves. I am using Debian Stretch.

```
www.domain.name > my website
application.domain.name > separate application
```

I read up about virtual hosts, but it seems to only specify for completely different domain names. Are there any meaningful differences and how should I configure my A records as well? I am very new to website hosting and any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Those are completely different names. I'm not sure what your question is?

Answer (score 0):

It's the same whether the second website is in the same domain or a completely different one.

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the apache examples page

```
# Ensure that Apache listens on port 80
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/example1"
    ServerName www.example.com

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/example2"
    ServerName www.example.org

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

Reference -> https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html